# SD card showing UUU.UUU error

Tags: sd-card

I have 32gb Samsung SD card. When I used it in my laptop having Ubuntu 14.04 LTS installed in it, SD card misbehaved. On opening the folder it didn't show up with any of my files or folders, but UUU.UUU files instead, which can't be accessed by me. I have formatted my SD card but it was of no use. How to fix this?

Comment: Can you read the SD card using other OS/ devices?

Comment: No. I tried to read it using Windows, but it also showed me same problem asked for permissions to format my card. When I read about it on internet, I came to know that its a virus. Please help me to remove it.

Comment: If you don't want the data, you can try to re-format the SD card. The easiest way to do so is GParted : https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/gparted/ .

Comment: I formatted my SD card but it is not working at all.

Comment: You need to make a new partiotion before being able to write data on the disk: http://www.wikihow.com/Use-Gparted

Comment: I made new partitions, but still I am unable to write. First time my partition worked perfectly but next time it crashed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29672/discussion-between-linux-lover-and-paulrx).